# Independence r.v. implies independence indicator functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume $n$ continuous random variables $X_k$ defined on the same probability space are i.i.d.  and integrable. Is it true that then also $\mathbb{1}_{\{X_k \leq x_k\}}$ for $k=$ $1\ldots n$  are pairwise independent random variables for all $x_k$?

Comment: Why do you think that $s_i$'s are independent?

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; $f\left(X_i\right)$ and $g\left(X_j\right)$ will be independent for any $f,g$ and $i\neq j$. As a special case, events $\left\{X_i\in A\right\}$ and $\left\{X_j\in B\right\}$ are also independent for any $A,B$ and $i\neq j$.